# Angular IE8 $index issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer-8, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have built a repeater that makes a couple of elements and puts them on top of each other.

In modern browsers this works just like i expected, but in IE8 it's buggy and doesn't parse the style part (I think the content of the style attribute is invalid and that's why it doesn't show).

It regards the following element:

```
<div class="leaf" ng-repeat="j in getNumber(number2) track by $index" 
    style="bottom: [[$index * 3 + 20]]px"></div>
```

Did anyone run into the same problem and has a proper fix for this or another way to do this.

Comment: Just quick suggestion: try ng-style, expressions should work there.

Comment: thanks worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked in the end:

```
    <div class="leaf" ng-repeat="j in getNumber(number2) track by $index" ng-style="
        {'bottom': '[[$index * 3 + 20]]px'}"></div>
```